# How to check if the user created with Firebase Google Auth is signing up or logging in? Unity C#

Tags: c#, authentication, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

I am creating a program that uses Firebase Google auth to SignIn/SignUp in c#. And Firestore as a database.  I need to save the data of new users who signup. But I don't know how to differentiate new user who signs up and old user who sign in using google auth.
How to find this

Nothing  i tried works.

```
    private void OnSignIn()
        {
            GoogleSignIn.Configuration = configuration;
            GoogleSignIn.Configuration.UseGameSignIn = false;
            GoogleSignIn.Configuration.RequestIdToken = true;
            AddToInformation("Calling SignIn");
    
            GoogleSignIn.DefaultInstance.SignIn().ContinueWith(OnAuthenticationFinished);
        }

    internal void OnAuthenticationFinished(Task<GoogleSignInUser> task)
        {
            if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                using (IEnumerator<Exception> enumerator = task.Exception.InnerExceptions.GetEnumerator())
                {
                    if (enumerator.MoveNext())
                    {
                        GoogleSignIn.SignInException error = (GoogleSignIn.SignInException)enumerator.Current;
                        AddToInformation("Got Error: " + error.Status + " " + error.Message);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        AddToInformation("Got Unexpected Exception?!?" + task.Exception);
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (task.IsCanceled)
            {
                AddToInformation("Canceled");
            }
            else
            {
                AddToInformation("Welcome: " + task.Result.DisplayName + "!");
               // AddToInformation("User Status: "+ task.Result.)
                AddToInformation("Email = " + task.Result.Email);
                AddToInformation("Google ID Token = " + task.Result.IdToken);
                AddToInformation("Email = " + task.Result.Email);
                SignInWithGoogleOnFirebase(task.Result.IdToken);
            }
        }
private void SignInWithGoogleOnFirebase(string idToken)
    {
        Credential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.GetCredential(idToken, null);

        auth.SignInWithCredentialAsync(credential).ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            AggregateException ex = task.Exception;
            if (ex != null)
            {
                if (ex.InnerExceptions[0] is FirebaseException inner && (inner.ErrorCode != 0))
                    AddToInformation("\nError code = " + inner.ErrorCode + " Message = " + inner.Message);
            }
            else
            {
                AddToInformation("Sign In Successful.");
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: we've come a long way with the availability of different frameworks and libraries that do all the heavy lifting for us. I would have said that you persist the data when they sign up and you check if the username (usually an email address or mobile number, etc) exist to see they are logging in. But considering how vague the question is I assume you have some frameworks doing all of this. Do you know what the frameworks are and how they have been implemented, if any?

Answer (score 0):

When `SignInWithCredentialAsync` completes, you get back a [`FirebaseUser` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/auth/firebase-user#class_firebase_1_1_auth_1_1_firebase_user). This object has `Metadata` property with two values: `CreationTimestamp` and `LastSignInTimestamp`. If those values are the same or really close to each other, the user was just created.